# MySQL InnoDB configuration

Tags: mysql

I would lik to create a MySQL InnoDB database. I use easyphp and phpmyadmin with: apache 2.4.7, MySQL 5.6.15 and PHP 5.5.8.
So I use an old access databse to create my new MySQL base but when I start the script of creation in the folder "MyBase" there are a lot of file "table1.frm" and the man who work with said that's not what he wants, he wants 1 big file create when the script start (something like access). Do you know how confugurate MySQL to do this??

thanks

Comment: Not sure that's possible with the frm files. There will be one frm file per table. Why does he want one big file for the database? If you want something like that try sqlite or firebird sql maybe.

Comment: He want something like this because he prefer copy and past the file than use a DUMP file. I have a SQLite database but he wants MySQL and he said it's possible but I don't know how